# Confusion on Initial condition on ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry this might sound pretty dumb but I just want to clarify something.

If i know the initial condition y(0) = 0, can I say y'(0) is also 0??

Comment: No. Unless your equation $y'=\dots$ leads to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example $y'' + y = 0$ is satisfied by $y(x) = \sin x$. The condition $y(0) = 0$ is met but $y'(0) = 0$ is not.

It's also worth pointing out that if you are solving a second order homogeneous ODE with conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 0$, then the only solution is the zero function. For instance the only solution to $y'' + y = 0$ with those two conditions is the zero function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y'=x+1$, then $y=\frac 12x^2+x+C$ and $y(0)=0$ implies $C=0$, but $y'(0)=1$.